# mod_jk modules for apache on Linux

Tags: linux, apache, mod-jk

Why does Apache website lists only two OS for mod_jk binaries?

I am confused about which version to download to install on Linux2.6.9 OS. From their website all I understand is that I have to download source and compile to create binaries for my OS? Am I correct?

I looked up tutorials on the net and they all seem to reference some old binaries for linux versions. If Apache did provide pre-compiled mod_jk modules why did they discontinue them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for [`mod_proxy_ajp`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html). It's supposed to be a newer replacement for `mod_jk`.

Answer (score 0):

As fas as i know you should always download latest one from http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/ compile it in your local system.

Answer (score 0):

Under Debian install it with apt-get:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk
```